# How Can I Recreate This UITableView Look?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Right now I have a standard UITableView that is empty by default and the user can add cells to it.

I noticed this app starts with no cells and is empty (like you cant see lines) but my standard view always has the lines like standard table view.

I thought it may be a grouped table style but the edges are not curved like the grouped style is.

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the separator lines by setting their color to the same color as your background, e.g.

```
tableView.separatorColor = [myApp theColorOfMyBackground]; // A UIColor object
```

Make sense?

The cells in your picture are likely custom cells, but you didn't really ask about that. :-)

EDIT: As noted in another answer `seperatorStyle` can be used to simply "turn off" the lines. That's a better way to do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  If you don't mind, could you elaborate on how to replicate the custom cell style?

Comment: Setting the `separatorColor` can work if (a) the background behind your tableView is a single, unchanging color, and (b) you don't mind the gap of a camouflaged line. The `separatorStyle` property can eliminate them altogether (I added an answer to that effect).

Comment: Subclass `UITableViewCell` as a starting point. You add custom views to its `contentView`, draw a gradient or set an imageView as a subview of its `backgroundView`. Just style it how you would any other view.

Comment: That's a long topic to answer here. :-) Basically, you subclass UITableViewCell and create a corresponding nib file with the layout you want, subviews, outlets, etc. In your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, instead of creating a generic UITableViewCell, you create an instance of your custom table cell object. (There are a variety of ways to do this and load your nib object too. Look at NSBundle's loadNibNamed: method.) You might also search more here at SO.

Answer (score 4):

The lines between cells are controlled by the `separatorStyle` property of your tableView. To remove the lines simply set:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Your other options are `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine` and `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. +1 What app is this? Does the view you show above actually "scroll" even though only 2 rows are showing? I am wondering if it is a truly a table view. It could be a series of UIViews added to a `UIScrollView` with a dark background.

Assuming the programmer knows how tall the "rows" are, then they can add them with a pixel spacing over the charcoal background. With the `UIScrollView`, the programmer can define the `contentSize`.

If more views were added to extend past off the screen and the `contentSize` was appropriately defined, the `USScrollView` would automatically allow scrolling at that point.

Selecting a "row" could be easily handled by UIGesture controls on each UIView.

***EDIT**

After seeing the app, Delivery by JuneCload, it is definitely using a UITableView with custom cell views. As Mark and Matt have answered.

Comment: This is called "Delivery" by JuneCload.  And yes it does scroll up/down/